# Flutter : Waiting for response of an alert dialog inside onWillAccept function of DragTarget

Tags: flutter, dart, promise, drag-and-drop, flutter-alertdialog

I have recently started learning Flutter and I am stuck at a point while dealing with Drag and Drop using Droppable and DragTarget. When I Drag my draggable element over DropTarget element, I am doing few validations in *onWillAccept* method. One of the conditions here requires me to confirm with user if they are willing to continue with their action before returning *true* and heading to *onAccept* method. For some reason, code execution does not wait for user's action to return.

This is how my DragTarget looks

```
DragTarget<Map>(
  builder: (context, listOne, listTwo) {
    return Container();
  },
  onWillAccept: (value) {
    if(condition1) {
      return true;
    } else if(condition2) {
      return true;
    } else {
      if(!condition3) {
        return true;
      } else {
        await _showConfirmation();
        return false;
      }
    }
  },
  onAccept: (value) {
    print(value);
  },
)
```

and *_showConfirmation* method looks something like this

```
Future<void> _showConfirmation() async {
  return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Attention'),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Some message")
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Accept'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              return true;
            },
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Cancel'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              return false;
            },
          )
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Adding await does not help as onWillAccept is not async. Making it async did not help either.

```
_showConfirmation().then((result) {
  return result
})
```

Above code did not help either. In many cases, the dragged item is left hanging over DragTarget box.

Any help regarding this will appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that Dart supports `await`? I don't know the language but can find evidence that its Futures have `.then()` and `.catchError()` methods.

Comment: Dart does support async/await https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await.
And I have also used .then() as per my last code block, but it did not produce expected results

Comment: OK. In that case the problem appears to be that the `onWillAccept` function is expected to return `true` (or presumably anything truthy) or `false` (or presumably anything falsy). After `await` on the previous line, it will return `<Future>`, which is truthy. I can't see how you can work round that other than submitting a pull request.

Comment: You could try ignoring `condition3` in `onWillAccept`, ie `else { return true }` then branching on `condition3` in the `onAccept` handler. Not sure exactly how to do it in Dart but you may need also to branch depending on whether the value delivered to `onAccept` is a `<Future>` or not. May not be exactly what you want but may stimulate thought.

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is that `_showConfirmation()` returns a Widget instead of a boolean - which what seems you're expecting from the snippet provided. The current setup lets false to be returned without waiting for the boolean value.

```dart
await _showConfirmation();
return false;
```

Instead of `_showConfirmation()` returning a Widget and proceeding to return false, you can wait for the value to be returned by using [then()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/then.html).

Change `_showConfirmation()` to return a boolean

```dart
Future<bool> _showConfirmation() async {
  ...
}
```

then call await before returning.

```dart
return await _showConfirmation();
```